# I made a full screen table but it interferes with navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am pretty new at HTML and CSS and I tried to make a full screen table that's responsive but becuase of it i can't use the navigation bar. It's probably because of the *position: absolute* property but i don't know how to change it without ruining it.

If i change the position: absolute property or delete it, the table is completely ruined.

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");

var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

var wsquare = 30, hsquare = 30;
var m = w / wsquare, n = h / hsquare;

for(var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow(i);
  for(var j = 0; j < m - 1; j++) {
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(j);
  }
}
```

```css
th, table, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PathFinding</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Name</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="table">
      <table id= "table">
      </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make some edit now your navbar work fine:

If you want to use absolute positioning, you can just add **position: relative;**  to the navbar and a higher **z-index*

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");

var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

var wsquare = 30, hsquare = 30;
var m = w / wsquare, n = h / hsquare;

for(var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow(i);
  for(var j = 0; j < m - 1; j++) {
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(j);
  }
}
```

```css
nav {
position:relative;
z-index: 2;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
th, table, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PathFinding</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Name</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
      <table id= "table">
      </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And is there any way to make the table start below the navigation bar?

Comment: Yes you can by adjusting value of top in table like **top:20px;**

Comment: you can adjust according to you requirement

Comment: Keep it up  it will take time, i recommend you to learn  **flex-box** and **grid** for modern and fast approach, grid and flex make life easy for Front-end development

Comment: I'm gonna search for some tutorial about them